# Vue.js open modal by click of a button

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-4

How to use a button to show the modal in other components? For example, I have the following components:

info.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <button class="btn btn-info" @click="showModal">show modal</button>
    <example-modal></example-modal>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import exampleModal from './exampleModal.vue'
export default {
  methods: {
    showModal () {
      // how to show the modal
    }
  },
  components:{
    "example-modal":exampleModal
  }
}
</script>
```

exampleModal.vue

```
<template>
    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            hihi
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

How to show the modal from exampleModal.vue? I know that I can 
use data-toggle and data-target to show the modal, like this:

`<button class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">show modal</button>`

But is there any way to show the modal by using the method "showModal"?

Comment: but which component do you want to display on click ? userInfoModal or  exampleModal ?

Comment: I want to show exampleModal on click. thanks, I have edited the question

Answer (score 12, accepted):

<del>According to your snippet, you're using a classic Bootstrap modal. You just need to use `data-toggle` and `data-target` attributes in that case:</del>

```
<div id="app">
  <div class="container">
    <button class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">show modal</button>
    <example-modal></example-modal>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

#### Edit

I misread the question so i edit my answer.

It's possible to open the modal with a custom method. You just need to find the element "#exampleModal" by using `refs` and then open the modal with a bootstrap method ([Bootstrap Programmatic API](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/javascript/#programmatic-api))

```
<div id="app">
  <div class="container">
    <button class="btn btn-info" @click="showModal">show modal</button>
    <example-modal ref="modal"></example-modal>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
methods: {
  showModal() {
    let element = this.$refs.modal.$el
    $(element).modal('show')
  }
}
```

[Fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/StpFlp_DDK/b96u796x/)

Comment: This is not working in `Nuxtjs`. I have created my `BootstrapVue` modal within my `components` directory. I have added it to my `pages` now when I try to restart my server I get the error `'$' is not defined`

Answer (score 6):

Without jQuery you could create a function on "method:" block like this:

```
openEditModal(data){
  // <handle with your data>
  this.$root.$emit("bv::show::modal", "your-modal-id");
}
```

Comment: This is the best answer

Comment: how would you do this if I'm not using BootstrapVue, just standard bootstrap4