# Disable all keypresses to elements behind modal

Tags: javascript, html, dom

In either Javascript or HTML, is there a way to disable all user input except for a selection of keyboard presses? For example, if I trigger an error that shows a popup error message, is there a way to block any other user input into the DOM in the backround until the user has dismissed the popup using the Enter key?

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: Is it a framework modal or your own?

Comment: @epascarello The popup is a modal from the Noty library in awesome-vue using Vue.js

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you might want to disable keyboard and mouse activity beyond the modal when opening like with [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22207377/disable-click-outside-of-bootstrap-modal-area-to-close-modal). Here is the summary of the options included:

If you opening the modal by js use:

```
$('#myModal').modal({backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false})
```

If you are using data attributes, use:

```
 <button data-target="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
    Launch demo modal
 </button>`
```

Comment: Thank you @MUlferts! The popup is a modal from the Noty library in awesome-vue using Vue.js. In the Noty library there is an option to make the popup a modal in the opts, do you know if there's a way to grab whichever modal is in focus in the DOM?

Comment: It looks like vue.js has a little different selector for opening a modal in javascript than with the jquery example above. [See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50428046/vue-js-open-modal-by-click-of-a-button) for an example of how to open from vue.js. You would have the DOM element in a variable if you opened this way instead of through an HTML button using data-attributes.